# How to open and use Library : "Fsharp.Charting && Fsharp.Charts" in Fsharp?

Tags: f#, fs, f#-data, fsharpchart

I tried my's best by finding a answer in Google . But all I think that it's not accordant with my case .
[image]

Please give me a guide . Thank you very much .

*If you were I , you can Uninstall + Install Visual Emprise .*

This's reasons takes me many times .

*Thank you everyone who help me in my difficulty .*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a reference directly to the DLL using the `#r` directive in your script.

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Charting.0.91.1/lib/net45/FSharp.Charting.dll"

open FSharp.Charting
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Fsharp.Charting reference in the references section of visual studio, and send to Fsharp.Interactive

then the below code will work

```
open FSharp.Charting

Chart.Line [ for x in 1.0 .. 100.0 -> (x, x ** 2.0) ]
|> Chart.Show
```